# SQL query to find at least one solution

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I have a bunch of table, say, Job and transactions

```
Job:

id   Name
4    Clay
6    Glow
7    Circle
9    Jam

Transactions

Id   Job_id      Person     Marks
2     6           Amy        0
3     3           Keith      30
5     3           Glass       10
7     9           Know       60
11    6           Play       81
13    6           Play       100
```

How do I find below return query which should return three column Job_id(Id of Job), Job_name(name of job) and level , which is one of three possible Strings: "Hard", "Easy", "Medium".

```
   **Job_id**       **Job_name**      **Level**
----------------------------------------------------
       4                Clay           Hard
       6                Glow           Easy
       9                Jam            Medium
```

Level is calculated if average score on Transactions, 
-- If average score for job is lower than or equal to 20, then its level is "Hard".
-- If average score for job is higher than 20 but lower than or equal to 60, then its level is "Medium".
-- If average score for job is higher than 60, then its level is "Easy".

I'm not sure if I should use a subQuery for this, or if there's an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is Clay's id 3 or 4?

Comment: Postgres or SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

```
select j.id,j.name,if(avg(t.marks)> 60,'Easy',if(avg(t.marks) <= 60 and avg(t.marks) > 20,'Medium','Hard')) as level from job j left join Transactions t on j.id= t.Job_id where t.id is not null group by Job_id
```

I just wrote down the query by looking at your data, it will be good if you provide schema with data in sqlfiddle etc. You can try above query

for SQLLite use as below

```
select j.id AS Job_id, 
   j.name AS Job_name,
CASE
WHEN avg(t.marks)>60 THEN 'EASY'
WHEN avg(t.marks)<=60 and avg(t.marks)>20 THEN 'MEDIUM'
WHEN avg(t.marks)<=20 THEN 'HARD'
END Level 
from job j 
left join Transactions  t 
on j.id = t.Job_id 
where t.id is not null
group by Job_id;
```

Comment: query return as wrong with no such function as if on SQLite v3.12

Comment: should refine with CASE instead of if for SQLite

Comment: Postgres (or standard SQL in general) does not have an `if` either

Comment: Was checking with Postgres syntax, that is all.

Comment: if you are using sqlite then you can write like below

    select j.id AS Job_id, 
       j.name AS Job_name,
CASE
WHEN avg(t.marks)>60 THEN 'EASY'
WHEN avg(t.marks)<=60 and avg(t.marks)>20 THEN 'MEDIUM'
WHEN avg(t.marks)<=20 THEN 'HARD'
END Level 
from job j 
left join Transactions  t 
on j.id = t.Job_id 
where t.id is not null
group by Job_id;